# Lavavel how to debug local.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent()

Tags: laravel

i am a laravel noob who has inherited an application

I have this problem that I am debugging. The user gets in a state of infinite loops or gets the error

`[2022-05-05 05:01:48] local.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line 65 {"userId":11794,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line 65 at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:412) [stacktrace`]

Where this is happening is in the

HomeController extends FrontController -> index()

when this code is called

```
return redirect('login');
```

I can fix the issue , by deleting all the users cookies via dev tools of the browser.

Would love some suggestions how to debug/fix this issue,

Thanks for any help

Comment: i suspect that this is not the code that's producing this error. It sounds like when you delete the cookies the redirect works fine, sort of indicating that this particular error is in one of the logged in states. I suspect that you need to look at what happens when a logged in user hits this route.

Comment: thanks for the response. Is there a best way to debug and determine what routes are being taken .   Yeah i know.. noob question

Comment: Laravel has a middleware called `RedierectIfAuthenticated`. There you should see the route location. That route is the one you should investigate first. (Default redirect is `home`)